# How to convert the String to html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, json

I am working in an application where I have generated a String that contains a mailbody, put HTML format. Now I want to show that in an alert which will exactly look like a browser like output. I am  giving my code here

```
mailBody = "<html>"
                                  +"<center> "      
                                  +"<body style='background-color: #e5e4e2;'> " 
                                  +"<table id='mainTable' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" 
                                  +"<tr> " 
                                  +"<td> "      
                                  +"<table style='width: 100%;background-color: #2B547E; height: 50px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> " 
                                  +"<tr> " 
                                  +"<td width='50%'><img src=\"cid:image\" height='50' width='150' style='padding-left: 10px;'></td> " 
                                  +"<td width='50%' style='text-align: right; color: white; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;'> </td>" 
                                  +"</tr> " 
                                  +"</table> "  
                                  +"</td> " 
                                  +"</tr>" 
                                  +"</table> " 
                                  +"<table id='mainTable1' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> " 
                                  +"<tr> "
                                  +"<td> "
                                  +"<table style='width: 100%; height: 50px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" 
                                  +"<tr> " 

                                  +"<td width='50%' style='color:red;font-size:21px;'>Congratulations, "+rsServeResource.getString(1)+" </td> " 

                                  +"<td width='50%' style='text-align: right; color: white; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px;'> </td> " 
                                  +"</tr> " 
                                  +"<tr> "
                                  +"<td style='font-size:18px;width:97%;font-style:italic'> "
                                  +emailText+" on "+interviewPhoneorOnsiteDate+" For " +rsServeResource.getString(2)+"  in   "+rsServeResource.getString(3)+" , "
                                  + "  You will be called at your mobile number "+rsServeResource.getString(4)    
                                  +"</td> "
                                  +"</tr> "
                                  +"</table> " 

                                  +"</td> "
                                  +"</tr> "
                                  +"</table> "
                                  +html
                                  +"<table id='mainTable2' style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:12px;'>" 
                                  +"<tr> "
                                  +"<td style='font-size:18px; color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic'> "

                                  +message

                                  +"</td> " 
                                  +"</tr> "
                                  +"</table> "
                                  +"<table  style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 70%; height: auto;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'> "
                                  +"<tr> "
                                  +"<td style='font-size:18px;color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold'> "
                                  +"Best Regards,"
                                  +"</td>"
                                  +"</tr>"
                                  +"<tr>"
                                  +"<td style='font-size:24px;color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold'> "
                                  +consultantName
                                  +"</td>"
                                  +"</tr> " 
                                  +"<tr>"
                                  +"<td style='font-size:18px;color:#2B547E;word-wrap: break-word;font-style: italic; font-weight: bold'> "
                                  +"Client Service Manager"
                                  +"</td>"
                                  +"</tr> "                               
                                  +"</td>"
                                  +"</tr>"
                                  +"</table>"
                                  +"</body> " 
                                  +"</center> " 
                                  +"</html> ";
```

So this is the String I am generating,from the java now what I have to do I have to show it in a boot strap that will give the exact browser like look and feel.

I am getting the String in a jQuery response like

```
             searchResultArray.put(mailBody);
             jsonFeed.put("searchResultArray", searchResultArray);
             resourceResponse.setContentType("text/html");
             resourceResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
             resourceResponse.getWriter().write(jsonFeed.toString());
```

And

```
 jQuery.getJSON(url+"&candidateId=" +candidateId+"&jobId="+jobId+"&text1="+text1+"&text2="+text2+"&text3="+text3+"&interviewVenue="+interviewVenue+"&interviewCC="+interviewCC+"&start-date="+startDate+"&interviewBCC="+interviewBCC+"&interviewCC="+interviewCC+"&interviewType="+interviewType+"&type="+type, function(data)  {  
    alert(data.searchResultArray)
});
```

That alert in returning the full HTML, how can I get a browser like feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create custom alert box and embed html with jQuery into it.

For example make a div:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

And than place html into it:

```
$("#message").html(mailBody)
```

Example fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nszag875/

**EDIT:**

Updated fiddle to work with bootbox (bootstrap alerts).

https://jsfiddle.net/nszag875/3

Comment: @your solution was nice but i want like a pop up can i use bootbox??

Comment: or can  you refer some custom alert box please ??

Comment: Yes you can use bootbox, here is updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nszag875/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JavaScript's inbuilt `alert()` method to do this job, it can't show something more than a string. For your purpose you can use some JavaScript libraries or jQuery plugins, such as jQuery Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/dialog), which uses jQuery UI. It will require you to make a `<div>` and append your string to that div. Like this :

```
$('#divYouCreated').html('Your string here');
```

As you said, you want to make your message popup, for that you can use animation with the modal box.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use jquery feature to append your string data as DOM element to DOM Tree
for example:

```
    var template = '<p> simple paragraph</p>'; // your string data
    var $template = $(template);
    $('#some-id').append($tamplate);
```